# bitnamiでインストールしたRedmineのアクセスURL変更方法

Tags: apache, redmine, bitnami

bitnamiでインストールしたRedmineのアクセスURL変更したいのですが、
初期状態では`127.0.0.1/redmine/`になっていますが、これを`127.0.0.1/ab12redmine/`に変更する方法が分かりません。

また、現在試みている方法として
・作成されたbitnamiフォルダ内のRedmineフォルダ名を変更し、Redmineフォルダを参照していたconfファイルの設定等の変更
・windows でのシンボリックリンク作成方法調査、および作成

分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

①コマンドプロンプトを管理者として実行し、下記コマンド実行

```html
cd C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.3-1\apps\redmine\scripts
serviceinstall.bat
```

②[C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.3-1\apps\redmine\scripts\serviceinstall.bat]内の、
「–prefix /redmine」と記載がある箇所の「/redmine」を変更したいURLに変更（変更箇所2箇所）
例）–prefix /redmine/test

③C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.3-1\apps\redmine\conf\httpd-prefix.conf]に記載されている下記項目の「/redmine」部分を変更したいURLに変更

ProxyPass /redmine ⇒ ProxyPass /redmine/test
ProxyPassReverse /redmine ⇒ ProxyPassReverse /redmine/test
BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001/redmine ⇒ BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001/redmine/test
BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002/redmine ⇒ BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002/redmine/test

④[C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.3-1\apps\redmine\htdocs\config\additional_environment.rb]に記載されている下記項目の「/redmine」部分を変更したいURLに変更

config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/redmine' → config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/redmine/test'

⑤コマンドプロンプトを管理者として実行し、下記コマンド実行

```html
cd C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.3-1\apps\redmine\scripts
serviceinstall.bat INSTALL
```

⑥[C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.3.3-1\manager-windows.exe]を起動
「Manage Servers」タブの「Restart All」ボタンを押下

Answer (score 1):

CentOS での設定変更の例で最新版でもないのでいろいろ変更があるかもしれませんが参考までに。

/opt/redmine-X.X.X-X/apps/redmine/conf/httpd-app.conf に以下の記載があり、これを変更することで似たようなことが対応できました。

```
PassengerPreStart http://127.0.0.1:80/redmine
```

↓

```
PassengerPreStart http://127.0.0.1:80/ab12redmine
```

また、/opt/redmine-X.X.X-X/apache2/htdocs/index.html にリンクがべた書きされているので、こちらも変更した方が良いでしょう。

```
<h1><a id="bitnami-link" href="redmine/">Access </a></h1>
```